# How to delete a variable string from a varchar

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on MySQL.

Do you know how I can turn these fields from column mailing_name

> Mailing A (53572/99564)
>
> Mailing B
>
> Mailing C (1211212/1532314)

into these ones ?

> Mailing A
>
> Mailing B
>
> Mailing C

The issue is the length of these last characters is not always the same :(

I managed to find which fields were concerned with

`IF (t.mailing_name LIKE '%(%/%)',1,0) as test,`

But I cannot replace them with

```
REPLACE(t.mailing_name,'(%/%)','') as test2,
```

I'm very interested in any idea.

Thanks in advance !

EDIT : Thanks a lot for the substring_index tip. Since sometimes I have several '(' in the field I ended up with :

```
IF (t.mailing_name LIKE '%(%/%)',SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.mailing_name,' (',LENGTH(t.mailing_name)-LENGTH(REPLACE(t.mailing_name,'(',''))),t.mailing_name) as test,
```

which works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **SUBSTRING_INDEX** to split it after the second space like this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('Mailing B (53572/99564)', ' ', 2);
```

**sample**

```
mysql> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('Mailing B (53572/99564)', ' ', 2);
+----------------------------------------------------+
| SUBSTRING_INDEX('Mailing B (53572/99564)', ' ', 2) |
+----------------------------------------------------+
| Mailing B                                          |
+----------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: Or, up to the first space followed by an opening paren e,g  `SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.mailing_name,' (',1)`

Comment: @spencer7593 - do you have seen that there is a space before ( . so the result have trailing space